# IE or FF Launcher

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to know if it's possible to develop an extension that allows to open a link with another browser : If in Chrome I click on a link that is configured in such extension, it opens FF or IE with this link.

I didn't find any extension (except extension that have a frame in a chrome tab), so does that mean that there is a technical limitation to do that ?
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I did something for FF what could be modified to do just that.

I have used the ability to execute shell commands from an extension, and configured the call to launch a 3rd party application.

Look for examples on [nsIProcess](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIProcess)

In chrome you can use the NPAPI plugins: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think that kms is correct in saying that you cannot execute native code in a Chrome Extension, and must therefore pair your extension with an NPAPI Plugin and have them talk to one another.  It was one of the most difficult programming tasks I've ever done, although the NPAPI Plugin was made easier by basing it on [FireBreath](http://firebreath.org), so at least I didn't need to write very much C++.

UPDATE: Since 2014 or so, Native Messaging is included in Chrome's Web Extensions API and, mercifully, NPAPI is gone.